# Kendo Splitter Nesting with Treeview

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview, nested, splitter

I am getting the error:

> Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguments

While creating a `Splitter` with Partial view rendered inside one of the panes of `Splitter`. The error is at `Content` property of the the pane. Please suggest me any changes to solve the problem

```
@(Html.Kendo().Splitter()
  .Name("vertical")
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:900px" })
  .Orientation(SplitterOrientation.Horizontal)
  .Panes(panes =>
  {
      panes.Add()
          .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "pane1" })
          .Resizable(true)
          .Size("300px")
          .Collapsible(false)
          .Content((@<text><div>@Html.RenderPartial("GetUsers", Model)</div></text>));
  })
)
```

Comment: If anyone else gets similar I think this error can be quite generic - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490823/kendo-ui-throwing-cs1593-delegate-system-action-does-not-take-1-arguments/55403648#55403648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the information from the following link I am able solve my problem. When you have to nest container controls of kendo UI you need to create a helper method for nested content and call the helper method as cotent for container control.

[Kendo widgets two level deep in Razor, inline markup blocks cannot be nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386283/kendo-widgets-two-level-deep-in-razor-inline-markup-blocks-cannot-be-nested)